# How create a CosmicMind CardTableView without AppDelegate Swift

Tags: swift, material-design, xcode8, appdelegate, cosmicmind

I need to create this view by calling it from another view, I need to be able to create the view without the appdelegate. I need help with this. Thanks

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

SampleData.createSampleData()

let graph = Graph()
let search = Search<Entity>(graph: graph).for(types: "Category")

var viewControllers = [PostsViewController]()

for category in search.sync() {
    if let name = category["name"] as? String {
        viewControllers.append(PostsViewController(category: name))
    }
}

let pageTabBarController = AppPageTabBarController(viewControllers: viewControllers)
let toolbarController = AppToolbarController(rootViewController: pageTabBarController)
let menuController = AppMenuController(rootViewController: toolbarController)
let leftViewController = LeftViewController()

let navigationDrawerController = NavigationDrawerController(rootViewController: menuController,
                                                            leftViewController: leftViewController
                                                            )

window = UIWindow(frame: Screen.bounds)
window!.rootViewController = navigationDrawerController
window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

return true
```

}

**This is my code, crash all time **

import UIKit
import Material
import Graph

class ViewController:PageTabBarController {

```
var window: UIWindow?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


open override func prepare() {
    super.prepare()
    SampleData.createSampleData()

    let graph = Graph()
    let search = Search<Entity>(graph: graph).for(types: "Category")

    var viewControllers = [PostsViewController]()

    for category in search.sync() {
        if let name = category["name"] as? String {
            viewControllers.append(PostsViewController(category: name))
        }
    }

    let pageTabBarController = AppPageTabBarController(viewControllers: viewControllers)
    let toolbarController = AppToolbarController(rootViewController: pageTabBarController)
    let menuController = AppMenuController(rootViewController: toolbarController)
    let leftViewController = LeftViewController()

    let navigationDrawerController = NavigationDrawerController(rootViewController: menuController,
                                                                leftViewController: leftViewController
    )

    window = UIWindow(frame: Screen.bounds)
    window!.rootViewController = navigationDrawerController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

}
extension ViewController: PageTabBarControllerDelegate {
    func pageTabBarController(_ pageTabBarController: PageTabBarController, didTransitionTo viewController: UIViewController) {

```
}
```

}

Comment: When you say create the view in another view, do you mean view controller? Also, why do you need to avoid the AppDelegate?

Comment: I want to call it from another UIViewController, I am using StoryBoard and creating some views programmatically, I can create my first view in the appdelegate but if I need to move to another as the example above, as I could do, some example.Thanks @CosmicMind

Comment: You can add the PageTabBarController as a child view controller to any UIViewController :) Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @JuanManuelMayobreLopez, Did you find the solution for the above question? I am new to iOS development and trying to find out how that will be done.

Comment: If you still need help with this, please provide the exact error messages you are getting. "crash all time" tells me nothing specific enough to know where to start looking for the source of the problem.